# Do I need a special switch for a bathroom fan?

Tags: electrical, bathroom

I am looking at replacing my two light switches in the bathroom. One is hooked up to a light and the other is for the bathroom ceiling fan.

I am guessing both of the switches are "Single-Pole Toggle Switch". I want to thinking of changing them both to "Decora Single Pole Switch 15amp".

Or do I need to use something different for the fan one? I know you can buy fancy ones for the fan that have timers and stuff but I just want a simple on and off switch.

Comment: You _can_ add a timer switch for the bath fan, or a humidity detecting switch if you desire. Be aware, though, that these _usually_ require a neutral in the switch box, and if your house was built before 2008, there's no guarantee that the box will have a neutral. It might have a white wire, but you'd need to do some testing to ensure that it's actually a neutral. Or, [ask a new question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) with a clear, focused, well lit pic of the wiring at the switch (do NOT detach any wires, and we'll be able to tell you if you have a neutral there.

Comment: My place was built in 2005 so might not have it but will check.

Answer (score 1):

Simple switches - old-style toggle switches or Decora switches - are really easy.

- Turn off the circuit breaker *or breakers*. Most likely you have one breaker that controls both the fan and the light, but it is possible to have two different breakers.
- Remove the cover plate.
- Remove the switches.
- **TAKE PICTURES**. Why? Because sometimes even simple setups have issues.
- Remove the wires from a switch. (Yes, one switch, not both.)
- Attach the wires to the new switch.
- Remove the wires from the other switch.
- Attach the wires to the new switch.
- Screw the switches back into the box.
- Turn on the breakers and test.
- If everything is good, install the new cover plate. If there are problems, turn off the breaker(s) to troubleshoot.

Simple switches have two screws with active wires. It does not matter, at all, top vs. bottom or left vs. right (most of the ones I have seen do top/bottom). However, if a screw had two wires connected under a screw before then it can get a bit messy as that is wrong and the solution (pigtail) is a little extra work.

If the old switches had ground wires attached then you will need to attach them as well (bare or green wires to green screws). However, many older switches don't have a ground connection and that's OK. If your switches are in a metal box then you don't need actual ground wires as the switches ground to the metal box automagically.

Comment: Switches ground to the metal box automagically _IF_ the box is properly grounded to the house wiring. Also, would recommend stepping up to the side-wire switches which do not require a loop around the screw, but simply clamp a straight wire under a clamp plate that is then tightened down. These will usually accommodate 2 wires under the single screw because they have 2 slots. +1!

Comment: Thanks for the steps and advice, yeah I watched some videos, at first I was not sure if the wires do need to go in a particular order, but that does not seem to be the case.  I will take some pictures and look at what is there before I start the job to see if there is any weirdness going on.